# How to gzip a body in a put call angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, gzip

So Currently using the

```
_http.put(url, body).toPromise()
_http.put(url, body, parameters).toPromise()
```

And I get an aw snap from chrome.

I want to compress the body before sending out.
Is there a library that does this?

Comment: You might take a look at: https://stuk.github.io/jszip/ but it's unclear to me if you can actually use this on the client-side, or only in Node.

Comment: zip != gzip. but yes, you can use `jszip` on client too (when you want to create zip file).

Answer (score 0):

You could use `pako` for client side gzip compression:

https://github.com/nodeca/pako

You will probably need to manually decompress on the server (if you use node, then you can use the same library). Take a look at this article, they tried to solve the exact same problem:

https://medium.com/axiomzenteam/put-your-http-requests-on-a-diet-3e1e52333014